# Can I pass the name of an attribute when it itself is being initialised?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaclass

I have a class in which I am defining several class attributes as objects. The name of the attribute itself is one of the arguments that need to be passed to the object. Currently they are written manually as in the below example:

```
class Beatles:
    john = Guitar(name='john')
    paul = Bass(name='paul')
    george = Guitar(name='george')
    ringo = Drums(name='ringo')

class Musician:
    def __init__(self)

class Guitar(Musician):
    def __init__(self, name)

class Bass(Musician):
    def __init__(self, name)

class Drums(Musician):
    def __init__(self, name)
```

I have found one work around that uses a metaclass to build the objects using the namespace dictionary of the Foo object:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        for k, v in dict_.items():
            if isinstance(v, Musician):
                dict_[k] = type(v)(k)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_)
```

This works only if the 'name' arguments are the only arguments which isn't going to be the case. Is there a better way?

Comment: while the question itself has technical merit, there are inherent problems with this design.  such as what happens when a band has 2 musicians with the same first name?  sure, you could now add another check, making sure the name is unique and altering with say middle name.  but... a) another big bit of complication and b) "Johnny B" is not a valid attribute name.  in the larger sense, yes, this is an issue with Python.  for example say a form.  each field may have a name, and it might be desirable to assign them as such to the form, but there is no link be between field.name and form.<attr>.

Comment: I think I saw something similar in Ramalho's Fluent Python, and he had no obvious easy solutions to bridging what's left and right of the assignment `=` operator, so the name was repeated.  In a later bit he did propose a hack of sorts, but, IIRC it was neither elegant, nor simple.  Unless you have overriding reasons to do something like this (such as being a core part of *ease of use* within a framework, with the warts hidden safely deep inside) then, in your position, I would just go with this limitation and work around them.  I doubt this issue is very specific to Python either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.6, there is a new feature to address this pattern, and diminish the need for metaclasses, as those almost always lead to confusion.

All that is needed is that the classes of the objects that are to be attributes have a  `__set_name__` method (in your case, those are all subclasses of `Musician`, so, all you have to do is to add a `def __set_name__(self, owner, name): ...`   method to it).

So, all that is needed in your case is:

```py
class Musician:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # no need to get a 'name' parameter here
        ...
    # This is called automatically by Python:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        # 'owner' is the class object where the attributes are defined in. 
        # in this case, "Beatles". It is usually not needed, but available.

        self.name = name

class Guitar(Musician):
    pass

class Bass(Musician):
    pass

class Drums(Musician):
    pass

class Beatles(metaclass=Meta):
    john = Guitar()
    paul = Bass()
    george = Guitar()
    ringo = Drums()
```

Now, if for some reason you want to implement this by using metaclasses (let's say you have to work on Python 3.5, or can't change the code on the `Musician` classes) - you could use functools.partial to store the other attributes and just pass the missing `name` attribute in the same metaclass code you have above:

```py
from functools import partial 

class Beatles:
    john = partial(Guitar, other_attribute='')
    paul = partial(Bass, wearing_shoes=False)
    george = partial(Guitar)
    ringo = partial()
```

(And keep in mind you can shorten `partial` for readability if desired, with things as simple as `from functools import partial as P` )

Answer (score -1):

The object itself doesn't exist yet, but the constructor is, ultimately a function, so you pass what you need as a function argument.

In this case, the example may not be conveying the question you want to ask. You don't have a name because you're a drummer, you have a name because you're a person. As the top level of the hierarchy, Musician would have that property, not Drummer, and it should be a parameter in Musician's constructor:

```
class Musician:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Guitar(Musician):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

class Bass(Musician):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

class Drums(Musician):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

Beatles = {
    Guitar(name='john'),
    Bass(name='paul'),
    Guitar(name='george'),
    Drums(name='ringo'),
}        

for m in Beatles:
    print (m.name)
```

Comment: I understand that this works, but it doesn't really answer my question. Perhaps the example wasn't clear, but I think the intent of my question was. The example is just using placeholder names. I need a class with attributes that are themselves, objects, not a dictionary of objects.